# How to load data in global memory into shared memory SAFELY in CUDA?

Tags: c++, cuda

My kernel:

```
__global__ void myKernel(float * devData, float * devVec, float * devStrFac,
int Natom, int vecNo) {

extern __shared__ float sdata[];
int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

float qx=devVec[3*idx];
float qy=devVec[3*idx+1];
float qz=devVec[3*idx+2];
__syncthreads();//sync_1

float c=0.0,s=0.0;
for (int iatom=0; iatom<Natom; iatom += blockDim.x) {
    float rtx = devData[3*(iatom + threadIdx.x)];//tag_0
    float rty = devData[3*(iatom + threadIdx.x)+1];
    float rtz = devData[3*(iatom + threadIdx.x)+2];
    __syncthreads();//sync_2
    sdata[3*threadIdx.x] = rtx;//tag_1
    sdata[3*threadIdx.x + 1] = rty;
    sdata[3*threadIdx.x + 2] = rtz;
    __syncthreads();//sync_3

    int end_offset=  min(blockDim.x, Natom - iatom);

    for (int cur_offset=0; cur_offset<end_offset; cur_offset++) {
        float rx = sdata[3*cur_offset];
        float ry = sdata[3*cur_offset + 1];
        float rz = sdata[3*cur_offset + 2];
        //sync_4  
        float theta = rx*qx + ry*qy + rz*qz;

        theta = theta - lrint  (theta);
        theta = theta * 2 * 3.1415926;//reduce theta to [-pi,pi]

        float ct,st;
        sincosf(theta,&st,&ct);

        c += ct;
        s += st;
    }

}

devStrFac[idx] += c*c + s*s;
}
```

why "__syncthreads()" labeled sync_2 is needed? Without sync_2, sdata[] get wrong numbers and I get wrong results. Line "tag_1" use the results of line "tag_0", so in my mind sync_2 is no need. Where do I wrong? If due to disorderd instruction executing, I should put a __syncthreads() in line "sync_4"?

Comment: `sync_2` should be at the bottom of the outer loop. You must ensure all thread warps have finished using the shared memory at a given iteration before any threads start loading new data to the shared array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider one warp of the thread block finishing the first iteration and starting the next one, while other warps are still working on the first iteration. If you don't have `__syncthreads` at label `sync2`, you will end up with this warp writing to shared memory while others are reading from that shared memory, which is race condition.

You might move this `__syncthreads()` at label `sync2` to the end of the outer loop for the sake of clarity.

["cuda-memcheck --tool racecheck"](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-memcheck/index.html#racecheck-tool) should tell you where the problem is.